# Why CSS Grid set the width of all items to the min content of the smallest item in a grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a simple grid that has 12 rows and a single column. I assume the width of each row is set to the min-content by default (my assumption) (picture 1). However, it seems like if I add a text to the first row which is a header, all rows' widths are resized instead of only the one I changed (picture 2).

To fix the issue, I can set the width of the grid to the value I need which will size all the rows properly. However, I would like to understand why CSS is positioning all the rows (label and input fields) to the min-content of a header element and not each row individually to its min-content

[image]

[image]

```
    #checkout-form fieldset {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 25px);
        align-items: start;
        /* this will align properly 
        width: 70%; */
    }

    #checkout-form fieldset>h2{
       grid-row: span 2;
     }
```

Comment: Please post all relevant code so we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's only one column all rows will have the same size, and they are based on the header element because it has the largest width. Why that happens? because that's [how it is specified](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#intrinsic-sizes), in other words, the default behaviour.

> In both inline and block formatting contexts, the grid container’s auto block size is its max-content size.

If you had defined the column size with the `grid-template-columns` property the following would apply.

> The max-content size (min-content size) of a grid container is the sum of the grid container’s track sizes (including gutters) in the appropriate axis, when the grid is sized under a max-content constraint (min-content constraint).

I'm not an expert at these documents btw.

Edit: does that answer your question?